# Separate the words by a space in a string using python

Tags: python

```
text = "Avalon:Sydney 04March2009Bondi Street at a conferencemeeting room234".
```

I would like to process the above string in such as way that the words are separated and not joined.

I would like the string to be printed as follows:

`"Avalon Sydney 04 March 2009 Bondi Street at a conference metting room 234"`

The string is now separated into individual words.

I would like to use the regular expressions but I failed.

```
text = "Avalon:Sydney 04March2009Bondi Street at a conferencemeeting room234"
newtext = re.sub('[a-zA-Z0-9_:]','',text)

print text
```

the above code does not work. Is there a better regular expression I can use to separate the words.

The regular expression should not be specific to the above sentence only, but a universal regular expression that can observe the above patters and separate into individual words in the same string.

Comment: First split on spaces.  `text.split()`.  Then check each item, and split on :, then write some code which could be regex to split the date

Comment: How would you define a rule that detects `conferencemeeting` are separate words?

Comment: I agree to that word conferencemeeting needs NLTK to split the word. But what about the rest of the joined words for dates and the words that are joined by special characters like : in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the colon with a space, use `.replace`:

```
text = text.replace(':', ' ')
```

To split parts of the text alternating between numbers and letters, you can use a *positive look behind* to catch words preceded by numbers or numbers preceded by words, and then substitute with a back reference with a leading space:

```
text = re.sub(r'((?<=[a-zA-Z_])\d|(?<=\d)[a-zA-Z_])', r' \1', text)
print text
# 'Avalon Sydney 04 March 2009 Bondi Street at a conferencemeeting room 234'
```

The splitting of `conferencemeeting` into separate words is not something that is up to regex, except of course, you could define a rule on which the splitting should be done.

Comment: thanks @Moses. Will check this logic and see how it works out.